# Wifi access point suddenly stops working

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, access-point

I use raspberry pi 3. I have followed the official documentation + some troubleshooting to get it to work. I will share my configuration files. I have a suspicion that it has something to do with my /etc/dnsmasq.conf, but I am not sure.

My `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=172.16.2.201/16
static routers=172.16.2.201
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

My `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=172.16.2.230,172.16.2.240,12h
```

My `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=myssid*
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword*
```

> * Note that ssid and wpa_passphrase are not real

My `/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

This is where I stopped following the documentation because I don't need internet access just the access point.

I left on my access point overnight and another raspberry connected to it. When I checked it the following day `myssid` was not showing and I have no idea why after I executed the following commands the access point was working again.

```
sudo systemctl unmask hostapd
sudo systemctl enable hostapd
sudo systemctl start hostapd
sudo reboot
```

Does my problem has something to do with this line `dhcp-range=172.16.2.230,172.16.2.240,12h` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`?

Comment: I had issues once with `hostapd`, which I couldn't solve. So I changed to `systemd-networkd` and `wpa_supplicant` and things are working since then. I followed [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/92303).

Comment: Thank you @jake will try it because the access point mustn't stop working.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of `hostapd` has changed since its latest update. If you have installed it with `sudo apt install hostapd` then its service is masked now. You have to configure it first and then *unmask* and *enable* it what you have done later. It should work now. I do not understand why it works the first time.

Comment: I did do that but after some time it stops working

Comment: @Stu076 do you get some information with `systemctl status hostapd.service` and `systemctl status systemd-networkd.service`?

Comment: Yes, their status is active (running)

Comment: @Stu076 That is trivial. I mean do you see some error messages/hints when the access point fails. You have to read the rest of the output. Can you please paste the output of the two commands into your question when the access point fails?

Comment: I think there were not any error messages. I tried jake's tutorial and is far better than the official one as it meets our company needs

Comment: @Stu076 Thanks for the praise to my tutorial :-)

Comment: you're welcome didn't know that was your tutorial. Can you help me with something else, please? I need to connect to my access point (your tutorial) with SSH  and pg_dump, but it doesn't work also I don't have my access point connected to the internet when I'm trying to connect it. Can you tell me how can I do it? I have asked a [question here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101342/cannot-ping-my-access-point)