# Cannot ping my access point

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-3b+, access-point, systemd-networkd

I created an access point on my Raspberry PI (Raspbian) following [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234) the systemd-networkd way. Now I have to connect to my AP via another RPI which I do with the help of nmcli with the following command:

`sudo nmcli device wifi connect MYSSID password MYPASSWORD iface wlan0`

I connect successfully but I also have to make a SSH connection and a pg_dump to my access point. And when I try the static IP I set it says it `can't connect to host MYIP port 22: no route to host.` I know that means that it can't find the IP, so how can I connect to my access point with SSH.

How I configured my access point.
General Configuration:

```
sudo -Es
systemctl mask networking.service dhcpcd.service
mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service
ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

`wpa_supplicant` configuration

```
cat > etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF

country=SI
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    psk="myPass"
    frequency=2437
}
EOF

chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Access point configuration:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF

[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=172.16.2.220
DHCPServer=yes
EOF
```

Access point configuration with eth0, no routing

```
cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF

[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=172.16.2.219
EOF

sudo reboot
```

Other RPI configuration

```
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome \
openvpn openvpn-systemd-resolved network-manager-openvpn \
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

And I have deleted `Wireless & Wired Network` from `Panel Applets`. On this RPI I have the `static IP (172.16.2.231)` configured with `dhcpcd`.

Edit: added configuration for my access point RPI and my other RPI

Comment: Welcome. You need to explain the context better here since `NetworkManager` is not used by default on Raspbian; `nmcli` isn't even installed (you don't say what OS you are using, so Raspbian will be presumed).  If you've added that but are combining it with the a `dhcpcd` configuration, you may not get predictable results.  Put another way, please edit *all* the details of what you've done to configure networking here (including the static IP).

Comment: @goldilocks I have added the details to my question, hope it's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should append a bit mask to your ip addresses. Without it, it is assumed that you mean to use the whole [class B network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) 172.16.0.0/16 with 65.536 ip addresses. But you have to ensure that the access point (**wlan0**) and the uplink (**eth0**) are on different subnets. Try to use this network files for the access point:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
EOF

cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
#DHCP=yes
Address=172.16.2.219/24
EOF
```

The ip address for **eth0** depends on the subnet that your internet router uses. Maybe you have to use another bit mask `/16` or any other. The simplest is to use the DHCP server from your internet router. Then you don't have to worry about the setup of interface **eth0**.

About the configuration of the other RPi I cannot help you. NetworkManager isn't supported by Raspbian out of the box and I have never used it with Raspbian. I don't believe that it works together with `dhcpcd`. You should consider just to use only default `dhcpcd` or also switch over to `systemd-networkd`.